# SQL query works fine when testing through phpmyadmin but fails when attempting the same thing in PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, variables, pdo, phpmyadmin

Okay from another users question on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22431809/mysql-count-consecutive-rows-with-the-same-value)  I have the following query:

```
set @test = 0, @id=0, @count=0;
select m.id, max(count)
from (
select 
 @count := if(TookTest = 1 and PatientID = @id, @count+1, 0) as count,
 @test := Tooktest,
 @id := PatientID as id
from medical) as m
group by m.id
having max(count) >=2;
```

this works fine in phpmyadmin but when I try the same in a PDO statement it fails with this error message:

PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error

```
$sql="set @test = 0, @id=0, @count=0;
select m.id, max(count)
from (
select 
 @count := if(TookTest = 1 and PatientID = @id, @count+1, 0) as count,
 @test := Tooktest,
 @id := PatientID as id
from medical) as m
group by m.id
having max(count) >=2;";

try{
    $stmt=$dbh->prepare($sql);
    if ($stmt->execute()){
        $rows=$stmt->fetchall();
    }
}catch(PDOException $s){
    echo $s;
}
```

Is there something I'm missing with this like you can't set variables in a PDO statement?

Comment: mysqli / pdo does not allow you do to multiple statements in one execution. ie select * from;select count from;

Answer (score 1):

Again its not the set variables that is the issue it's trying to run two queries simultaneously. So I needed to change the above code to this:

```
$sql="set @test = 0, @id=0, @count=0;";
try{
    $stmt=$dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute()
}catch(PDOException $s){
    echo $s;
}

$sql="select m.id, max(count)
from (
select 
 @count := if(TookTest = 1 and PatientID = @id, @count+1, 0) as count,
 @test := Tooktest,
 @id := PatientID as id
from medical) as m
group by m.id
having max(count) >=2;";

try{
    $stmt=$dbh->prepare($sql);
    if ($stmt->execute()){
        $rows=$stmt->fetchall();
    }
}catch(PDOException $s){
    echo $s;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Those two queries

```
set @test = 0, @id=0, @count=0;
select m.id, max(count)
from (
select 
 @count := if(TookTest = 1 and PatientID = @id, @count+1, 0) as count,
 @test := Tooktest,
 @id := PatientID as id
from medical) as m
group by m.id
having max(count) >=2;
```

Can be rewitten as one query so you only need one prepere statement

```
  select m.id, max(count)
    from (
    select 
     @count := if(TookTest = 1 and PatientID = @id, @count+1, 0) as count,
     @test := Tooktest,
     @id := PatientID as id
    from medical) as m
    cross join ( select @test := 0, @id := 0, @count = :0 ) as init_user_params
    group by m.id
    having max(count) >=2;
```